# An equivalence relation on the isomorphism classes of finite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let all groups be finite. I am interested in the equivalence relation on finite groups given by $G \sim H$, if and only if, there exist $W_1,W_2,Z$ with $W_1 \cong W_2 \unlhd Z$ so that $G \oplus Z/W_1 \cong H\oplus Z/W_2$.

The most obvious question to ask is when are two groups equivalent. A necessary condition is that they have the same order. In the case, if the two groups are abelian this is sufficient. This can be worked out from the classification of finite abelian groups and the fact $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n} \sim \mathbb{Z}_{p^n-1} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p$. This means abelian groups under this relation are isomorphic to the positive integers under multiplication.

Can anyone provide two groups of the same order that are not equivalent? I was not able to do it for the case $S_3,\mathbb{Z}_6$.

The reason I am interested in the question is because I recently saw the definition of topological K-theory. I was interested if there was some interesting way to mimic it for the case of groups. For various reasons, I decided that before forming the Grothendieck group, I wanted the elements to be of the form $G-H$ (with addition component wise direct sum) where $H \leq G$. It should also have the property that $G+H-H=G$. The idea behind this is that for any subgroup $H$ we are formally introducing another subgroup to act as a complementary summand to $H$. However, if the subgroup already is a direct summand these should coincide. But if we are treating subgroups like direct summands, it only makes sense to also require that if $H \unlhd G$, then $G-H \sim G/H$, from which you get things like $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n} \sim \mathbb{Z}_{p^n-1} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p$.

It was a hassle to find the equivalence relation generated by this, but it ended up being: $G_1 - H_1 \sim G_2 - H_2$, if and only if, there exists $H_1,H_2 \unlhd F$ and $W\cong\bar{W} \unlhd Z$ so that $F/H_1 \oplus G_1 \oplus Z/W \cong F/H_2 \oplus G_2 \oplus Z/\bar{W}$.

So the monoid I am interested in is the set of formal differences $G-H$ with $H \leq G$, quotiented out by this equivalence relation. The question in the first paragraphs is what you get when you ask when $G \sim H$ in this monoid. It's worth noting that nontrivial inverses don't exist, and the operation remains cancellative even after quotienting. I think this means the Grothendieck group will contain pretty much the same information as this monoid.

So to reiterate, $\textbf{Can anyone provide two groups of the same order that are not equivalent?}$. I think a good pair to check might be a perfect group and an abelain group. If this question ends up being too easy, feel free to talk about the structure of the monoid.

Comment: In fact, I think you can form the Grothendieck group by just relaxing the requirement that $H \leq G$.

Comment: So what is $Z$, you don't say?

Comment: @ancientmathematician Z is a finite group. F is a finite group. W is a finite group. These all vary.

Comment: Any two finite groups equivalent under your relation must have the same composition factors.

Comment: @DerekHolt Is this because $Z/W_1$ and $Z/W_2$ have the same composition factors? I suppose you say this because you are using a composition series that takes advantage of the fact it splits as a direct sum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I said in my comment, if two groups are equivalent, then they must have the same composition factors. This follows from the Jordan-Hõlder Theorem, because $W_1 \cong W_2$ implies that $Z/W_1$ and $Z/W_2$ have the same composition factors.

The converse is also true. Any two finite groups with the same composition factors are equivalent. (So in particular any two solvable groups of the same order are equivalent.)

To show this, it is sufficient to show that any finite group is equivalent to the direct product of its composition factors. This is clear for simple groups $G$ so suppose $G$ is not simple, and let $N$ be a minimal nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$. By induction, it is sufficient to show that $G \sim G/N \times N$.

Let $H = G/N \times N$, and let $\sigma:G \to G/N$ and $\tau:H \to G/N$ be the natural homomorphisms with kernel $N$. Let $Z$ be the subgroup $\{(g,h) : \sigma(g) = \tau(h)\}$ of the direct product $G \times H$, and let $W_1 = \{(n,1): n \in N\}$ and $W_2 = \{(1,n):n \in N\}$.

Then $W_1 \cong W_2 \cong N$ with $W/N_1 \cong H$ and $W/N_2 \cong G$, so $G \times W/N_1 \cong H \times W/N_2 \cong G \times H$, and hence $G \sim H$.

Comment: Ah, your first paragraph is what I was missing! Thank you. I see a simpler argument on why $G/N \times N \sim G$: Let $H=G \times N$, and quotient the first copy of $N$ from the $G$ and the second copy from the $N$.

Comment: I think your proof also readily extends to the classes of simulataneously Artinian and Noetherian modules over some ring.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Yes I agree with both comments! In fact my group $W$ is isomorphic to $G \times N$. I used the more complicated construction because I was originally trying to show that any two extensions of $N$ by $G/N$ were equivalent, but then I realized that I could just take one fo the two groups to be the direct product.

Comment: One interesting question is if this is the finest equivalence relation compatible with direct sum that identifies all solvable groups of the same order. For some reason I suspect yes. Or perhaps you also need the requirement it is compatible with quotients.